# Get screen height in WP8 Silverlight app on page initialization after tombstoning

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, constructor, screen-resolution, tombstoning

For some reason, I need to get the device screen height in the page constructor and use it to set the sizes of other page items. I do it like this:

```
double screenHeight = Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize.Height;
```

However, I've recently detected that this code fails if the app comes out of tombstoning and this page is the active page. In this case, `Application.Current.RootVisual` is null.

How to overcome this, or are there other methods to get the screen height?

Comment: Hit `ActualHeight` instead.

Comment: @ChrisW., where can I find this property?

Comment: The parent layoutroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize` returns screen resolution. If that is what you want, use `Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight` instead:

```
double screenHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```